# JS Validate Crossword Clue Enumeration

Tags: javascript

I need to validate a crossword clue's enumeration (the number(s) in the brackets). For example, "Big star (3,5)" - the enumeration is `3,5`.

I'm struggling with the required regular expression. Rules should be as follows:

- only allow characters 0-9, hyphens and commas
- each number shouldn't start with a zero e.g. "09" should be just "9"
- it should start with a number
- it should end with a number
- it shouldn't allow repeated hyphens/commas e.g "3,,5" or "3--5" or "3,-5" or 3-,5"

Some VALID examples...

- 1
- 1,2
- 1,2-3
- 1,2-3,4

Some INVALID examples...

- text
- -1
- 1,
- 1,,2
- 0-1
- 3-04

Hopefully you get the idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are very powerful but can be a pain to write out sometimes, especially if you don't use them often. This is why I often use [this site](https://regexr.com/) to help.

After speaking in the comments, a logic error became apparent: the regexp would not match anything with `0`, even if it did not start with it. It would also not match numbers without `-` like just `10`.

Now, I came up with `([1-9]([0-9]+)?(((\-|\,)[1-9]([0-9]+)?)+)?)` but there was another problem:

- `10-5-40` would be matched as expected
- but the `3-2` in `03-2` and the `3 and 2` in `03-02` would also be matched.
  So I included some JS logic in addition to the RegExp. Hopefully now it works as intended.

```js
let Regexp1 = /([1-9]([0-9]+)?(((\-|\,)[1-9]([0-9]+)?)+)?)/;
let Regexp2 = /([1-9]([0-9]+)?(((\-|\,)[1-9]([0-9]+)?)+))/;

function test(t) {
  match1 = (t.match(Regexp1) != null);
  match2 = (t.match(Regexp2) != null);
  
  let matches = false;
  
  if(match1 && match2) {
    matches = true;
  } else if(match1 && !match2) {
    if(t.match(Regexp1)[0].length == t.length) {
      matches = true;
    } else {
      matches = false;
    }
  }
  
  if(t.match(Regexp1)[0].length != t.length) {
    matches = false;
  }
  
  console.log(matches);
  return matches;
  
}

test("10-5"); // true
test("03-4"); // false
test("0-5"); // false
test("1,05"); // false
test("1--5"); // false
test("10"); // true
test("10-05"); // false
```

Comment: Thanks AlphaHowl. I'm not sure the reg exp is working exactly how I'd expect though. Only allowing characters 1-9 means that anything with 10 will fail e.g. `test('10-4')`. Also, single numbers don't seem to work as it looks like it's expecting a separator e.g. `test('1')`.

Comment: I edited my answer, hopefully it works now

Comment: Yeah that's much better, thanks! FYI I had to add a short circuit to one of the conditions to prevent a null error.

Comment: Here's the final version all working:

```const isEnumValid = (enumStr) => {
  const match1 = enumStr.match(/([1-9]([0-9]+)?(((\-|\,)[1-9]([0-9]+)?)+)?)/);
  const match2 = enumStr.match(/([1-9]([0-9]+)?(((\-|\,)[1-9]([0-9]+)?)+))/);

  let valid = false;

  if (match1 !== null && match2 !== null) {
    valid = true;
  } else if (match1 !== null && match2 === null) {
    valid = match1[0].length === enumStr.length;
  }

  if (valid && match1[0].length !== enumStr.length) {
    valid = false;
  }

  return valid;
};
```